# remove subfolders from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently I have a rewrite rule to redirect you to the subfolder that has the website in it

> (www.dejongetestsite.site refers to www.dejongetestsite.site/TKLive2/upload)

but as soon as I click another page it adds the subfolders back in. I can manually enter `http://www.dejongetestsite.site/store` and it works like it should. Is there another rule that I can write that will remove the `/TKLive2/upload` from all urls

Answer (score 0):

Please take the time to read the PHP Manual on the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function. The manual is your friend.

Aside from that, I ran this in my browser

```
$string = "www.dejongetestsite.site/TKLive2/upload";
$string = substr($string, 0, -15);
echo $string;
```

And it outputs

```
www.dejongetestsite.site
```

As for .htaccess, I think (don't quote me) it may be this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/TKLive2/(.*)$ http://www.dejongetestsite.site/$1 [L,R=301]
```